# How to let the user fill the rest of the url link in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, url, hyperlink

I am working with xcode and I'm stuck in writing URL links. I want the user to fill the rest of my written URL code.

Here's the code:

**- (IBAction)openURL:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://facebook.com/....."]];
}**

The user will see this:
facebook.com/*write your address here...*

The "*facebook.com/*" part is a label and the "*write your address here...*" a textfield that is filled in the apps settings. For example I can write "JJMLS" in settings, so the result is "facebook.com/JJMLS".

I have sat a custom/invisibile "openURL" button over the result area.

How can I tell xcode that @"http://facebook.com/(.....)" part is an area that should get the JJMLS result when the user fills it???

I will really appreciate some help!

-JJ

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
- (IBAction)openURL:(id)sender {

    if(textfield.text == nil){

        UIAlertView *noTextAlert = [UIAlertView initWithTitle: @"No text entered!"
                                                      message: @"Please enter some text"
                                                     delegate: self
                                            cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok"
                                            otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [noTextAlert show];
    }

    else{

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://facebook.com/%@", textfield.text]]]; 
    }
}
```

If you have any questions about the code, just put it in the comments. Hope this helps!